# Display disappears when I connect external HDD

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, display, hard-drive

I am completely new to raspberry pi.I have a raspberry pi2 and have loaded the raspbian linux that came with it. Now i want to use my old sata hdd for which i have bought a 3.5 inch casing(which works properly.. connected to my laptop.) As soon as i connect this to my pi. the display goes and as sson as i remove it ti comes back. donno why this is happening. hdd is ntfs formatted. what do i need to do to make this work. please help

Edit: display goes means the screen goes black like it is turned off. i.e it looks as if the machine is off. but as soon as i remove the hdd the screen comes back on. it does not restart

Comment: You might want to explain explicitly what you mean by "display", since there are a variety of possibilities here.

Comment: Unless the drive has a separate power supply it won't work powered via the Pi.  The USB ports might supply enough for a laptop 2.5" drive, but they won't have enough power for a 3.5" drive.

Comment: the casing has its own powersupply. so i dont think its drawing power from the pi

Answer (score 2):

This is a power problem.

For the Raspberry Pi 2, make sure your power supply is rated for 5V at 2A.

For external hard drives it is highly recommended that you use a powered USB hub as well.

Comment: it has its own power and i dont think its drawing power from the pi. but thanks ill check if the power is right

Answer (score 1):

> it has its own power and i dont think its drawing power from the pi

Just in case, try editing `/boot/config.txt` and add:

```
max_usb_current = 1
```

Contra Patrick, it does not matter how large or high quality a supply you use, without this set all models but the 3 will default to underpowering the USB ports, and things such as external hard drives will not work.

The (older) A/B models will not power such a device no matter what you do, and you must use a hub.  The newer +/2 models should be fine with the setting above enabled, presuming there aren't any other high power USB devices attached (keyboard, mouse, wifi adapter are okay) *and* the total supply is >= 2A.  If the device then boots with the red power LED flashing, your supply is insufficient; if you are using a charger plus microUSB <-> USB cable, try another cable.  They are not all created equal.

**You must reboot in order for this to take effect.**

Although it is not documented there, you can find out [more about `config.txt` here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt.md).